# Why does load affect the output?

Tags: amplifier, motor

I have this circuit:

[image]

It is a differential motor driver.

I do not understand why the output changes when the motor is connected.

With no load, the output is correct — a perfect X for a waveform from Out1 increasing linearly from 0 to 5V and Out2 decreasing from 5V to 0.

When the motor is connected, I get an elongated X:

[image]

Why does it do that? Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Comment: The question this is marked as a duplicate of doesn't seem to answer this at all. Other than pointing out a mistake in that question's schematic and saying it's a class B amplifier all it says is that you'll get crossover distortion with a load, but doesn't explain why.  I was in the middle of answering when this one was closed. :|

Comment: I agree with @GodJihyo and thus have voted for a reopen.

Comment: The output transistors must be included in the opamp negative feedback loop to cancel the change in losses of the output transistors by load current. I made a schematic bit it cannot be attached to this comment and there is no 'answer" to attach it.

Comment: The collector of Q4 seems not wired ...

Comment: Yes I am aware the schematic has Q4 not connected. a typo -- it is connected

Comment: i have a feedback loop that i process and change the voltage at the input accordingly.  Can you explain "crossover distortion" and why it only happens under load ?